# Holomorphic function with real part is positive on circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ holomorphic function on$\{z|1\leq |z|\leq 2\}$
If $\operatorname{Re} f>0$ on $\{|z|=2\}$, there exist $z$ s.t., $|z|=1$ and $\operatorname{Re} f\geq 0.$

My idea: if $\operatorname{Re}f<0$ on $\{|z|=1\}$, there exist closed curve $\gamma$ in $\{z|1\leq |z|\leq 2\}$ s.t., $\operatorname{Re}f=0$ on $\gamma$. But I can't make contradiction.

Comment: Assume $Re(f)<0$ on $|z|=1$. Use [Schwarz reflection principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle) to extend $f$ to $1/2\leq |z|\leq 1$. Then $Re(f)>0$ on $|z|=1/2$. Continue reflecting deeper inside to get a extension to $0<|z|\leq2$. But $f$ is bounded near $0$, and therefore analytic there. It must follow that $Re(f)(0)=0$ because there are arbitrary small circles around the origin in which the real part is alternates signs. But by the argument principle $f$ doesn't take pure imaginary values inside $|z|<2$.

Comment: Take into account that taking reciprocal and conjugation (the operations needed to do the reflections on the circles) doesn't change the sign of the real part. That is what gives you the concentric circles in which the real part is positive and the concentric circles in which the real part is negative.

Comment: @cactus there is an assumption on $Re f$ on the boundary $|z|=2$, but it is not assumed that $f$ is real on $|z|= 1$. How do you apply the reflection principle?